# Скачать видео и звук благодаря Youtube_dl в Python скрипте

Tags: discord, discord.py, ffmpeg

создаю небольшого Discord бота для скачивания видео и аудио по ссылке. Я хочу сделать, чтобы помимо звука, у меня качалось и видео. Код:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl
import ffmpeg
import ffprobe

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='youtube.',
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
     print("Ready")

@bot.command()
async def youtube(ctx, content):
     if "https://youtube.com/*" or "http://youtube.com/*":
          ydl_opts = {
               'format': 'bestvideo/best',
               'postprocessors': [{
                    'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                    'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
                    'preferredquality': '192',
                }],
            }
            with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
                 ydl.download([f'{content}'])
```

Оно скачивает аудио, но не видео. Может кто помочь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pytube import YouTube

# URL видео, которое вы хотите скачать
video_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=your_video_id"

# Создание объекта YouTube
yt = YouTube(video_url)

# Выбор наилучшего доступного формата видео
video = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()

# Загрузка видео
video.download(output_path="путь_к_папке_для_сохранения")

print("Видео успешно скачано!")
```